# Unable to save a JsonElement type field to Cosmos DB

Tags: json, serialization, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When I save a model into No sql cosmos db instance using entity framework core. It does not persist the JsonElement JobParams whereas the jobParamsJson string is good. I require the hashmap like object JobParams to be actually persisted in the db as it is being consumed by other clients too.

The JobParams field in the cosmosdb document created looks like

```json
{  
   ValueKind:1   
}
```

Comment: Please edit to provide all relevant details. You've only shown one field and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cosmos v3 SDK uses `Newtonsoft.Json` as serializer by default, while `JsonElement` is an object that is used by `System.Text.Json`. Since it is not decorated with a custom `JsonConverter` from `Newtonsoft.Json` it will serialize it with its properties which causes it to display it like that.

If you want to make use the `System.Text.Json` you could create a serializer for it. Here's [example from Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/SystemTextJson/CosmosSystemTextJsonSerializer.cs):

```cs
public class CosmosSystemTextJsonSerializer : CosmosSerializer
{
    private readonly JsonObjectSerializer systemTextJsonSerializer;

    public CosmosSystemTextJsonSerializer(JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions)
    {
        systemTextJsonSerializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(jsonSerializerOptions);
    }

    public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        using (stream)
        {
            if (stream.CanSeek
                   && stream.Length == 0)
            {
                return default;
            }

            if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
                return (T)(object)stream;
            }

            return (T)systemTextJsonSerializer.Deserialize(stream, typeof(T), default);
        }
    }

    public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
    {
        var streamPayload = new MemoryStream();
        systemTextJsonSerializer.Serialize(streamPayload, input, input.GetType(), default);
        streamPayload.Position = 0;
        return streamPayload;
    }
}
```

Then just add it to your options when creating the `CosmosClient` instance:

```cs
var client = new CosmosClient(accountEndpoint: uri, authKeyOrResourceToken: key, clientOptions: new()
{
    Serializer = new CosmosSystemTextJsonSerializer(),
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for answering my query.

Actually I am using EntityCoreFramework and there seems no way to use a Custom Serializer with cosmos provider

There is this open issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17306

By any chance, any idea how we can get it to work with Entity Framework Core with Cosmos provider

Comment: Ah sorry, missed EF. Unfortunately no, although since EF uses `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` internally the same serializer as above could be passed on if they ever allow you to define a custom serializer in its options.